# How to show console log progressively?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

When I execute  powershell script that call Install-ChocolateyPackage or Update-ChocolateyPackage, the console log show on only after the script finish executing,

I want the script to print log progressively, how can i do that please ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the select mode

[image]

when console is in select mode, messages don't show up progressively
 to disable it just unckeck *Properties>>Quick Edit Mode*